# What can be causing an "exceeded process limit" error?

Tags: php

I launched a website about a week ago and I sent out an email blast to a mailing list telling everyone the website was live. Right after that the website went down and the general error log was flooded with "exceeded  process limit" errors. Since then, I've tried to really clean up a lot of the code and minimize database connections. I will still see that error about once a day in the error log. What could be causing this error? I tried to call the web host and they said it had something to do with my code but couldn't point me in any direction as to what was wrong with the code or which page was causing the error. Can anyone give me any more information? Like for instance, what is a process and how many processes should I have?

Answer (score 1):

Wow. Big question.

Obviously, your maxing out your apache child worker processes.  To get a rough idea of how many you can create, use top to get the rough memory footprint of one http process. If you are using wordpress or another cms, it could easily be 50-100m each (if you're using the php module for apache).  Then, assuming the machine is only used for web serving, take your total memory, subtract a chunk for OS use, then divide that by 100m (in this example).  Thats the max worker processes you can have.  Set it in your httpd.conf.  Once you do this and restart apache, monitor top and make sure you don't start swapping memory.  If you do, you have set too high a number of workers.

If there is any other stuff running like mysql servers, make space for that before you compute number of workers you can have.  If this number is small, to roughly quote a great man 'you are gonna need a bigger boat'.  Just kidding.  You might see really high memory usage for a http process like over 100m.  You can tweak your the max requests per child lower to shorten the life of a http process.  This could help clean up bloated http workers.

Another area to look at is time response time for a request... how long does each request take?  For a quick check, use firebug plugin for firefox and look at the 'net' tab to see how long it takes for your initial request to respond back (not images and such).  If for some reason request are taking more than 1 or 2 seconds to respond, that's a big problem as you get sort of a log jam.  The cause of this could be php code, or mysql queries taking too long to respond.  To address this, make sure if you're using wordpress to use some good caching plugin to lower the stress on mysql.

Honestly, though, unless your just not utilizing memory by having too few workers,  optimizing your apache isn't something easily addressed in a short post without detail on your server (memory, cpu count, etc..) and your httpd.conf settings.

Note: if you don't have server access you'll have a hard time figuring out memory usage.

Comment: Am I supposed to run top on my own machine? I am using Wordpress but it's nothing special at all. I'm also using 1 MySQL server.

Comment: @user1770047 ssh into the server running apache, then run top on the server machine to see process size.  If you hit 'm' while running top, it will sort by memory usage highest to lowest.

Comment: @user1770047 I see you're not using php_mod, but fast CGI.  Read my update about request time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have server access. I'm completely in the dark.

Comment: @user1770047 I'd start profiling the amount of time a request takes to see if that looks bad.

Comment: I will try doing that! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The process limit is typically something enforced by shared webhost providers, and generally has to do with the number of processes executing under your account.  This will typically equate to the number of connections made to your server at once (assuming one PHP process per each connection).

There are many factors that come into play.  You should figure out what that limit is from your hosting provider, and then find a new one that can handle your load.

Comment: What is a PHP process though? I'm so confused. We do have a shared hosting account.

Comment: If PHP is being executed via CGI or FastCGI, it is a process on the system just like executing anything else.  If PHP is being ran as a module, it is built-in to the web server.  Basically, your hosting provider has additional limits that they didn't disclose to you.  You need to figure out what those limits are so you know what you need when you go to shop around for a new host.

Comment: PHP is being executed using CGI on our web server. Should I find a web host that runs PHP as a module?

Comment: @user1770047, No, that isn't the issue.  You need to find a web host who allows a higher process limit that you need.  Or, talk your current one into raising the limit.

Comment: I'm really confused about what is causing so many processes. We have another website with the same hosting plan and that website does a lot more with PHP than this one does, yet it's never had a problem.

Comment: @user1770047, "Does a lot more with PHP" is meaningless.  What matters is how many processes there are running simultaneously.  Look, there is a process spun up for PHP every time PHP is executed via CGI/FastCGI to process a page.  If you have a PHP page that streams its output, and maybe that page uses 4 resources that are also rendered by PHP, you have the potential of 5 simultaneous processes right there in one page load.  If you have a page that takes longer to process, you will have processes out there longer, increasing the chance of more simultaneous.

Comment: Thank you all of the help so far. I'm sorry for being such a pain asking so many questions. I just want to get a good  understanding of this. What does "streams its output" mean? Does streaming output mean pulling data from the database and outputing that information into html? And what is defined as a resource?

Comment: @user1770047, No pain at all.  What I mean by streaming output is that PHP and your server are configured to send output to the client as it is sent from your application.  Otherwise, output from your application is buffered until it is complete, and then sent to the client.  If the output is streamed, the browser may start parsing and loading other resources from your server before the base page has finished processing. This is a **good** thing generally.  A resource... anything you're loading in your page.  You're overcomplicating the problem. You need your process limit raised.  That's all.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't something wrong that I did on my part. Because if it were, I want to be able to fix it. I will ask that they raise the process limit in the future if it becomes a problem (which I'm sure it will when traffic on the website increases). Thanks again for the help!